# android studio org.json.JSON.typeMismatch

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-volley

How can I get JSONObject which has Array in it in volley?

## Logic

[image: one]

## Code

> Note: I'm aware that my api function below works if my result is JSON
>   Array, but I'm not sure how to modify it in order to get JSON Object
>   (as my result is)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts)

    callAPIDemo()
}

// api code
private fun callAPIDemo() {
    val mySlugValue: String = intent.getStringExtra("my_slug")
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val url = "https://example.com/api/categories/$mySlugValue"

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            val jsonArray = JSONArray(response)
            val list: ArrayList<Post> = ArrayList()
            for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                list.add(parseData(jsonObject))
            }
            // here you will have the complete list of data in your "list" variable
            posts_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            Log.d("my list", list.toString())
            posts_list.adapter = MyPostsRecyclerViewAdapter(list)
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        })
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}

// parsing data
private fun parseData(jsonObject: JSONObject): Post {
    var listingObject = Post(
        jsonObject.getString("name"),
        jsonObject.getString("slug"),
        jsonObject.getString("image")
    )
    return listingObject
}
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

As requested here is how my returned code looks like:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "name": "...",
  "slug": "...",
  "icon": "...",
  "body": "...",
  "image": "...",
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "user": "...",
      "name": "...",
      "slug": "...",
      "image": "...",
      "body": "...",
      "icon": null,
      "quote": null,
      "video": null,
      "created_at": "2019-11-23 06:05:56",
      "updated_at": "2019-11-23 06:53:26"
    },
    // other posts
  ],
  "created_at": "2019-11-23 05:35:31",
  "updated_at": "2019-11-26 11:25:17"
}
```

Comment: you will need to learn how to parse JSON, so in all cases you can parse the coming JSON data. please check this https://blog.mindorks.com/parsing-json-in-android

Comment: Please post your Json code

Comment: @Ajeett you mean result i get for this domain (https://example.com/api/categories/$mySlugValue) ? if so, in my screenshot is pretty obvious all the rows and names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse your json data like this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts)

    callAPIDemo()
}

private fun callAPIDemo() {
    val mySlugValue: String = intent.getStringExtra("my_slug")
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val url = "https://example.com/api/categories/$mySlugValue"

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->

                val list: ArrayList<Post> = ArrayList()
                getPosts(response,list)

                // here you will have the complete list of data in your "list" variable
                posts_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                Log.d("my list", list.toString())
                posts_list.adapter = MyPostsRecyclerViewAdapter(list)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
            })
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}


fun getPosts(response: String,list:ArrayList<Post>) {

        var jsonObject = JSONObject(response)
        val jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts")

        for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
            val jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
            var listingObject = Post(
                    jsonObject1.getInt("id"),
                    jsonObject1.getString("user"),
                    jsonObject1.getString("slug"),
                    jsonObject1.getString("image"),
                    jsonObject1.getString("body"),
                    jsonObject1.getString("icon"),
                    jsonObject1.getString("quote"),
                    jsonObject1.getString("video"),
                    jsonObject1.getString("created_at"),
                    jsonObject1.getString("updated_at")

            )
            list.add(listingObject)

        }
}
```

And your data class will look like this

```
data class Post ( val id: Int, val user: String?, val slug: String?,
                      val image: String?, val body: String?, val icon: String?,
                      val quote: String?, val video: String?, val created_at: String?,
                      val updated_at: String?
    )
```

Comment: @mafortis what is url dll.?

Comment: sorry by dll i meant etc. :) like in my version of function i have url to get data from as well as `adapter`

Comment: @mafortis provide Post data class

Comment: here you go `data class Post (
    val name: String,
    val slug: String,
    val image: String
)`

Comment: it doesn't get category data? if you check my screenshot again in my page first i show my category body (description `if not null`) then below that i show posts of that category. i think your current code only gets posts of category and not included category data itself right?

Comment: also i'm getting this error `ui\CategoryPosts\posts.kt: (32, 35): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected`

Comment: the error comes from my adapter file not class wait i send you screenshot...

Comment: @mafortis If you want body also then i suggest you can get it directly instead getting this also in list and then set it to your Body `TextView`.
`var body:String = JSONObject(response).getString("body")`.
Add the line above your list initialization

Comment: body isn't so important as long as i can get posts of category i think is ok for now

Comment: @mafortis, If my answer solved your problem kindly consider accepting it.

Comment: it didn't bro, i am sending you screenshots of errors :))

Comment: The screenshot you attached says that it's a warning because we defined the string value as nullable, as they can be null

Comment: The second error is not related to this question. Its related to your adapter.

Comment: it was actually, you were using `val user` while it was `val name` anyway it fixed now. thank you so much

Comment: Yes you have to rename the references